# Call postgresql record's field by name

Tags: postgresql, record

I have a function that uses RECORD to temporarily store the data. I can use it - it's fine. My problem is that I can't hardcode columns I need to get from the RECORD. I must do it dynamically. Something line:

```
DECLARE
  r1 RECORD;
  r2 RECORD;
BEGIN
  for r1 in Select column_name 
            from columns_to_process
            where process_now = True
  loop
    for r2 in Select * 
              from my_data_table
              where whatever
    loop

       -----------------------------
       here I must call column by its name that is unknown at design time
       -----------------------------
       ... do something with
       r2.(r1.column_name)

    end loop;
  end loop;
END;
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

best regards
M

Comment: Where does the dynamic column name come from?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to select the all the qualifying rows and compute the total in a loop. Actually when working with SQL try to drop the word loop for your vocabulary; instead just use sum(column_name) in the select. The issue here is that you do not know what column to sum when the query is written, and all structural components(table names, columns names, operators, etc) **must be known** before submitting. You cannot use a variable for a structural component - in this case a column name.  To do that you must use dynamic sql - i.e. SQL statement built by the process. The following accomplishes that: See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6950a0bbd516700f212d853a17c2cd3c).

```
create or replace function sum_something( 
          the_something text                 -- column name 
        , for_id        my_table.id%type     -- my_table.id 
        ) 
   returns numeric
  language plpgsql 
as $$
declare 
    k_query_base constant text := 
        $STMT$ Select sum(%I) from my_table where id = %s; $STMT$; 
    l_query      text;
    l_sum        numeric;      
begin 
    l_query = format(k_query_base, the_something, for_id); 
    raise notice E'Rumming Statememt:\n %',l_query;  -- for prod raise Log
    execute l_query into l_sum; 
    return l_sum;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of declaring `k_query_base constant text` over just using the string literal in the `format` call?

Comment: Admittedly, it is stylistic, but I think there is value.   Long strings in the  execution section of the block  (begin ... end) tend to  get in the way of just seeing the flow of code at a glance. Now for a one line query it is not so bad but how about to query 20-25 lines or more. To me removing them for the execution section makes the code clearer. I consider that as the most important thing in writing code.  Further to be consistent I always do that way . But technically NO a string literal will accomplish the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer Belayer is not answer to the question. I know your approach and I use it, but not in this case. Here I MUST use record and get values of the fields dynamically (for example iterating through and checking if there is any negative ... or so... does not matter). I MUST call field of the record by its dynamically changed name! Like this r.('dynamically called column - always different');

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some time I figured out that I could use temporary table instead of RECORD. Doing so gives me all advantages of using dynamic queries so I can call any column by its name.

```
DECLARE
  _my_var bigint;
BEGIN

  create temporary table _my_temp_table as
  Select _any, _column, _you, _need
  from _my_table
  where whatever = something;

  execute 'Select ' || _any || ' from _my_temp_table' into _my_var;

  ... do whatever

END;
```

However I still believe that there should be a way to call records field by it's name.